# Data modelling in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am trying out Cassandra and looking at ways to model our data in it. I have described our data store requirements along with my thoughts on how to model in Cassandra. Please let me know whether this makes sense and suggest changes.

Did quite some search on the web, but didn't get clear idea regarding how to model multi-valued column requirements and index it, which is quite a common requirement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Our current data for each record:**

```
{
  ‘id’ : <some uuid>,
  ‘title’ : text,
  ‘description’ text,
  ‘images’ : [{id : id1, ‘caption’: cap1}, {id : id2, ‘caption’: cap2}, ... ],
  ‘videos’ : [‘video id1’, video id2’, …],
  ‘keywords’ [‘keyword1’, ‘keyword2’,...]
  updated_at: <timestamp>
}
```

**Queries we would need**

- Lookup by id
- Lookup by images.id
- Lookup by keyword
- All records where updated_at >

**Our current model**

1. Column Family: Article
   id: uuid
   title: varchar
   description: varchar
   images: 
   videos: 
   keywords: 
   updated_at: 
   updated_date:  [eg: ‘2013-05-06:02’]
2. Column Family: Image-Article Index

   ```
   {
     ‘id’ : <image id>, 
     ‘article1 uuid’ : null, 
     ‘article2 uuid’ : null,
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Column Family: Keyword-Article Index

   ```
   {
     ‘id’ : <keyword>, 
     ‘article1 uuid’ : null, 
     ‘article2 uuid’ : null,
     ...
   }
   ```

**Sample queries:**

1. Lookup by id => straight forward
2. Lookup by images.id =>

   ```
   ids = select * from ‘Image-Article Index’ where id=<image id>
   select * from Article where id in (ids)
   ```
3. Lookup by keyword =>

   ```
   ids = select * from ‘Keyword-Article Index’ where id=<image id>
   select * from Article where id in (ids)
   ```
4. All records where `updated_at > <some timestamp>`

   Cassandra doesn’t support range queries unless there is one equality condition on one of the indexed columns.

   extract date and hour from given timestamp;

   ```
   for each date:hour in start to current time
       ids = select * from Article where update_date=date:hour and timestamp > <some timestamp>
       select * from Article where id in (ids)
   ```